# Laptop Making rattling/vibrating noise

Tags: laptop, fan

My laptop is making rattling/vibrating noises intermittently. If I constantly tap/hit a point on my laptop just to the right of my trackpad (that's where the noise seems to be coming from, but it's not too close to my speaker) the noise stops. I think this is the fan, but the fan sounds the same when the laptop is not rattling. What could the problem be, and how do I address it?

Video of problem:

https://youtu.be/e0kL-7wy3nc

Specs:

Model: Dell Inspiron 14 5480

Processor: Intel i5-8265U (Integrated Graphics, no dedicated graphics card)

RAM - 8 GB DDR4 2100 MHz

256 GB SSD

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like a bad bearing in the fan. I looked at a picture of a breakdown of the internals of your laptop, and that’s the only moving part.

Replacing the fan should solve the issue.

Comment: I just opened the laptop after I heard the rattling to remove dust from the fan, it looked fine. How would I gauge if something was wrong with the fan when looking at the internals?

Comment: You won’t be able to see the bad bearing, or lack of oil on the shaft. The fan would look normal. You could open it up CAREFULLY turn it on while open and stop the fan with your finger to see if the noise stops. You’d want to make sure you’re grounded to the laptop before touching any of the internal. The fact that you have an SSD rules out hard drive noises. I would just order a new fan and replace it.

Comment: The rattling noise seems to have become less frequent and is now practically non-existent, how could the problem disappear all of a sudden?

Comment: Not sure, it’s hard to guess why. In your video you ran didn’t sound like it had very consistent RPMs either. You can either choose to continue using it as is or replace it.

Comment: Yeah, turns out I had to replace the fan, works like a charm now!